# How to change Extjs4 CSS for specific panel

Tags: css, extjs

i am working in extjs4. i have view with ganttChart. I want to change color of splitter line which is between treecolumn and gantt. i am creating gantt as=

```
 var gantt = Ext.create("Gnt.panel.Gantt", {           
           itemId :'project-list-gantt-chart',

            cls : 'projectlistganttchart',
            enableTaskDragDrop: false,
            columnLines :true,
            lockedGridConfig :{
                split: false 
            },
            viewPreset : 'customPreset',
            columns : [{
                xtype : 'treecolumn',
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'Name',
            }],
```

And i am including this gantt in my following form panel=

```
Ext.define('GanttChart' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
   border: false,
})
```

By using panel's add method i am including it as-
    afterrender : function(){
       var me = this;
       me.add(gantt);
    }

So for changing color, i change css as-

```
.x-panel-default{
    border-color: red;
    padding: 0;
}
```

But its changing color of all panels within my project. So how to override this css so that it will change color of only gantt.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `ui` cfg param for that:

```
// add this config line to your panel that host the gantt
ui: 'gantt'
```

and add this css

```
.x-panel-gantt{
    border-color: red;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Note that the `ui` is meant for exactly such things.

You might want to refer to this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1va). Note that it may miss some css classes but I guess it should show you the trick. And please note that you will need to set the border in a correct way because based on the theme the border might be 0px. That is also done in the example. In addition here is the demo code:

Javascript

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'test',
    height: 200,

    width: 200,
    ui: 'custom',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
})
```

CSS (just copied from developer tools)

```
.x-panel-body-custom {
    color: black;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-size: normal;
}

.x-panel-custom{
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 0;
}

.x-panel-body-custom {
    background: white;
    border-color: #157fcc;
    color: black;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-size: normal;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.x-panel-header-custom {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #157fcc;
}
.x-panel-header-custom-horizontal-noborder {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.x-panel-header-custom-horizontal {
   padding: 9px 9px 10px 9px;
}
```

Comment: thanx for help..But its not working. i added config line and css. Its not changing color of line.

Comment: @user1722857 Yeah I forgot that this will affect all css classes former named `.x-panel-default` will now be named `.x-panel-gantt`. Anyway this is the way I would go because you get a maintainable style which you loose with every line of code that apply styles. But all in all it is up you and just changing a line color may be such a minor change in your eyes that the afford of creating a custom ui might be to much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use id of the component(panel) itself or any top level id of the component in which the panel is rendered like

```
#toplevelid .x-panel-default{
   border-color: red;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanx for reply sir..Actually id for gantt is created dynamically.So how to define css in such case

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get your `gantt` item and change the `css` `class` of it using something like:

```
var ganttItem = Ext.getCmp('your item id');
ganttItem.addCls('your css class for specifc color');
```

I haven't tested this but you can get the idea.
If you want to reset the css class for the item use `.setCls()` to set it up from scratch.

Comment: i tried as you said as-               me.queryById('project-list-gantt-chart').addCls(project);   and css added as                                                      .project{
    border-color: red;
    padding: 0;
}  but its not working.